# sling SSL configuration with proper "sling:match"

Tags: java, ssl, adobe, aem, sling

I am using Adobe CQ 5.6 and implementing SSL configuration according to the following link.
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/config-ssl.html
The SSL is now configured, but not working against a particular URI match. I want any url ends with "abc.html" should open through SSL.

Like : 
`http://localhost:5402/content/xyz/abc.html` should replace with `https://localhost:5433/content/xyz/abc.html`

Now can someone please tell me for above, what should be the value of property "**sling:match**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following mapping should do the trick:

```
/etc/map
      +-- http
           +-- localhost.5402
                +-- abc
                     +-- sling:match = "(.*)/abc.html"
                     +-- sling:redirect = "https://localhost:5433/$1/abc.html"
                     +-- sling:status = "301"
```

`localhost.5402` matches hostname and port. The `abc` mapping matches all requests with `/abc.html` suffix and redirects it to the `https` domain using HTTP status code 301 Moved Permanently.

You may also consider using Apache's *mod_rewrite*. Appropriate rules would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    =localhost
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  =5402
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/abc.html$ https://localhost:5433/$1/abc.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tomek Rekawek. It woks absolutely fine.

Comment: if I do not give the port number then how it will be possible to redirect to https? for example: /etc/map/http/somedomain.com